# Add identity column to Send Log data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

Is there a way for me to create an Identity column (as primary key) on a Send Log data extension?

I'd like to be able to update the Data Extension, but in order to do so, I need a primary key column.

We use the send log as a means to Archive emails sent from Marketing Cloud. Every hour we have an automation that exports data in the send log, and removes the items from the send log that were exported. My problem is that the send log is filling up with sends that we don't intend on archiving. I'd like for a way to remove these items from the send log. One way I was thinking was to reference the send log data extension's primary key. I'll try using the _CustomObjectKey as Adam Spriggs pointed out.

Comment: What's your use-case for upating SendLog column values?

Answer (score 2):

There's a hidden column named `_CustomObjectKey` in every Data Extension, if that helps.  There's more info on it here on the [SFMC wiki page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/).

There's nothing stopping you from inserting any kind of value you want into the SendLog at send time with AMPScript, as long as it's meaningful to you.  You don't necessarily need to make it a primary key to retrieve and update values in a specific row.

I probably would not recommend updating column values in the SendLog.  They're generally huge and unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam mentioned, modifying records in the SendLog is not suggested. It's meant specifically to be a snapshot of each send at send time. Much like you wouldn't want to modify a visitor log, as then you wouldn't have an accurate record of the original visit.

You could consider creating a new data extension to facilitate whatever data manipulation you intend to do, and pass the needed information to it at send time. That would allow you to have access to the data, while leaving the SendLog untouched.